# Lexical scoping in golang?

Tags: go

I don't quite understand why `a` is not 2 at the end:

```
func main (){
    z := 4
    if true {
        z := 2
        fmt.Println(z)
    }
    fmt.Println(z) // prints 4
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://play.golang.org/p/lZFMDGF_M_).

Comment: I've changed the example to better explain the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`z` is getting [shadowed](https://golang.org/doc/go1#shadowing). Change `:=` to `=` and it will work.

```
func main (){
    z := 4
    if true {
        z = 2
        fmt.Println(z)
    }
    fmt.Println(z) // prints 2
}
```

The if statement has its own scope, when you used `:=` you declared a new variable and shadowed the old one.

Answer (score 0):

This does not even compile (*I was answering the unedited version of the question*).

You have to use `;` instead of `,`:

```
func main(){
  a := 0
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    a += 5
  }
  fmt.Println(a) // prints 50
}
```